# CSS Make Scrollbar Go On Top of Div Instead of Making it Smaller

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to style a div very exactly, but the scrollbar is getting in the way. The div has a padding-right of 20px. When the scrollbar is present on the right-hand side, it squishes the div.

Instead, I want the scrollbar to take up some of the padding space. Is this possible with CSS styling (not Javascript checking and manipulation)?

EDIT: Some things I cannot do:

1. Use JavaScript to check whether or not the scrollbar is present.
2. Set a fixed width for the div.

Comment: try `box-sizing: border-box` if it dont work, come back here with a relevant piece of code so people will be able to help you in a proper way;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways to do it:

```
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

or:

```
div {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

where 100% is the div width and 20px is the padding value, reduced of the total;